# Числа и цифры в маске?

Tags: yii2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как для input при использовании виджета MaskedInput, указать маску вида:
AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA, только чтобы можно было вводить не только буквы но и цифры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый вечер.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'phone')->widget(MaskedInput::class, [
  'mask' => ['***-***-***-***'],
  'options' => [
    'placeholder' => 'AAA-AAA-AAA-AAA'
  ]
]);
```